# Developing android applications with Eclipse, removing header from layout

Tags: java, android, layout, header

I'm learning how to develop android applications through a book from the for dummies (you can take that literally) series using Eclipse.

I have created a few layouts now using linerlayouts, scrollviews, ... and each time I show the Graphical layout in Eclipse or run the application in the Emulator, in the top of the screen the application icon, application name and a blue line beneath it are displayed. I have no idea how they get there (they don't seem to be declared anywhere in the xml file) and how to get rid of them.

I have been searching for "remove header" and stuff like that but that doesn't seem to get me any closer to finding a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using XML in your AndroidManifest.xml file in the activity element:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Or with code:

```
requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
```

Comment: do you have any idea what is the "best" solution?
personally I'd think adding the line of code to the XML because it looks like a cleaner way, but that's just gut feeling

Comment: Yes, the XML way is cleaner because it gives a better overview in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity under `onCreate()` use:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

This will create a "full screen" effect.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#requestWindowFeature(int)